# How do I find integer solutions to this nonlinear equation with two unknowns and several other constraints?

Tags: combinatorics

Constraints:

$$
xy+x+y=n
$$
$$
0 \le x < m
$$
$$
0 \le y < m
$$
$$
x \ne y
$$

Given integers $n$ and $m$, with $n>0$ and $m>1$, how do I find the integer solutions for $x$ and $y$? I have found specific solutions [via WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x*y%2Bx%2By%3Dn,%20x!%3Dy,%20x%3E%3D0,%20y%3E%3D0,%20x%3Cm,%20y%3Cm,%20n%3D5,%20m%3D5) but am unable to find a general solution in terms of $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Hint:  $xy + x + y + 1 = (x + 1)(y + 1)$.

Answer (score 2):

$xy + x + y = n$

$x(y+1) + y = n$

$x(y+1) + (y+1) = n + 1$

$(x+1)(y+1) = n+1$.

Factor $n+1$ and find all possible values of $x$ and $y$.
If possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "Factor n+1"?

Comment: [Integer factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization)

Comment: I mean take the number $n+1$ and factor it.  If $n = 17$ then $n+1 = 18$ and it factors to $1\times 18$ or $2\times 9$ or $3\times 6$.  So solutions are $x=0,y=17,x=1,y=8,x=8,y=1,x=17,y=0$.